# Azure Machine Learning Studio append rows to dataset

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, ml-studio

My "experiment" is like this,

[image: Experiment]

I have 10 rows (excluding header) in "Dataset.csv" and 3 rows (excluding header) in the CSV being imported by *Import Data*. The schema of both CSVs is same. I want *Add Rows* to **append** the 3 rows to Dataset.csv.

The real "Dataset.csv" has more than 25,000 rows and is expected to grow. Hence, using *Export Data* to generate a merged dataset (as a new CSV) is not a feasible solution. Any way to implement **append** for this scenario?

Thanks

Update 1:
Dataset.csv is present in ML Studios *Dataset*.

[image]

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. You're unable to use the CSV generated by "Export Data"?

Comment: @Jon I am unable to use the CSV to update the existing dataset. And by dataset, I mean ML Studios' dataset (see Update 1).

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36132435/186013) where you can't update a dataset that's uploaded to Azure ML, but it looks like you can you can upload with a different name, remove the original dataset, and rename the new one. I believe [this](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-MachineLearning-ClientLibrary-Python) is the SDK for it.

Comment: Oh, looking at the SDK, it may be possible to just update the dataset with the `update_from_dataframe` method.

Comment: I will look into these links, but the real problem is that I can't always delete and re-upload the dataset. It's at 400 MB right now and is expected to grow :)

Comment: The update method should be exactly what you need, I think :)

Comment: @Jon `update_from_dataframe` worked brilliantly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out the [Python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-MachineLearning-ClientLibrary-Python) has an `update_from_dataframe` method on it that can be used to update a dataset that has been uploaded to Azure ML Studio. If you're unable to use a new CSV and need to update an existing data set, then this should do the trick.

Comment: Any way to achieve the same via Azure Functions?

Comment: Microsoft's documentation for this,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/python-data-access

Comment: Interestingly, Azure Functions doesn't fully support Python. However, it is [in the works](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/13250616-will-you-support-python-on-functions).

Comment: AF version 2 will no longer have Python support. But have you come across any library in C# that can append rows to the dataset (similar to how the Python SDK does it)?

Comment: I think it will have Python support in v2 due to [this repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker). It is still early in its development so the docs about supporting it may not be updated yet. It would be really weird if they didn't support Python :)